# How to enable autocomplete backwards in terminal on shift + tab?

Tags: macos, terminal, autocomplete

I activated autocomplete in a Unix/Linux bash terminal. Now I would like to use autocomplete backwards on SHIFT + TAB.

My code for autocomplete is:

`set completion-ignore-case on
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
TAB: menu-complete`

I would like to have a shortcut for making the "undo" when I want to go back with the last option.

Comment: menu-complete-backwards